# How to calculate the purging low-fee for a node with the default mempool size?

Tags: transaction-fees, bitcoin-cli, mempool

I'm running a full node with a mempool size set to 2 GB. Default mempool size is 300 MB.
At the moment (block hight 785,095) the mempool size is around 344 MB.

Running rpc command

```
bitcoin-cli getmempoolinfo
```

on my node returns the value for "mempoolminfee":  0.000010 --> 1.0E-5, multiplied by * 100000 = 1 sat/vB.

This means that my node currently accepts transactions with a fee rate at 1 sats/vB. I'm happy with this setup.

According to [mempool.space](https://mempool.space), at the moment, the node with a default mempool size of 300 MB will only accept transactions with a fee rate greater than 1.38 sat/vB.

I would like to calculate myself the "purging low-fee" (1.38 sat/vB) for a node with a default mempool size.

Can I calculate the purging low-fee using the bitcoin-cli on my node? I would like to get to that value with my hardware. Running a second node with default mempool size is currently not an option.